# Natural numbers object via initial morphism

Tags: category-theory, recursion, natural-numbers, topos-theory

I assume that a [natural number object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number_object) (or see [nLab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/natural+numbers+object)) can be defined as an [initial morphisms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_property).

(edit: as in the title, I ment initial morphism, not objects)

[image]
$\hspace{1cm}$
[image]

Thoughts: Probably $X:=1$, and the object map of $U(N)$ is the digram... but no, in this case it wouldn't be "for every '1 over q to A over f to A", becuase if the diagram is encoded in the functor, the universal quantification isn't over the $f$. Also, how would the initial morphism definition enforce that there is only a single $u$ involved in the recursion scheme that's being produced?

I probably only need to know the right functor and then it's done.

Comment: It's not clear from the problem statement whether you are assuming an existing category or trying to construct a category with a certain property.  The mention of knowing "the right functor" adds to my confusion, since a functor maps one category to another.

Comment: It's really unclear to me what the second diagram is supposed to represent. The Wikipedia article indicates what sense the natural number object is an initial object in the category $1\to A\to A$. Initial objects do not necessarily have anything to do with functors.

Comment: The second diagram comes from the definition of a universal morphism.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: Write, I wrote *object*, but I ment *morphism*. How can the NNO definition be stated in terms of initial morphisms.

Comment: Why would you think it could? Initial morphism is defined in terms of a functor, but there is no default functor one could use here.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Well, yeah I'm asking for the functor. I expected it because there is a formulation in terms of initial object and when they can be defined in terms of a universal property, then NNO could too.

Comment: "When they can be." Initial objects can always be defined in terms of universal property, in the rigorous sense of that Wikipedia article? If you can prove that, then you'd be done, no?

Answer (score 3):

You want to look at the category of diagrams

$$ 1 \to A \to A $$

where the two copies of $A$ should be interpreted as being the *same* object, rather than two separate objects of the index category that happen to map to the same object.

Comment: Notice that this is precisely the category of algebras for the endofunctor $X \mapsto 1+X$.

Comment: Sure, but "category of algebras" is a more advanced concept, and this approach is way more accessible. @MartinBrandenburg

Comment: I didn't want to judge anything, just add the connection to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

An NNO is an initial object in the category of algebras for the endofunctor $X \mapsto 1+X$.